# Create Record-like type from union type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In Typescript I created a union type with a shared "type" property:

```
export type Instruction =
  | { type: 'local.set', name: string, value: Expression }
  | { type: 'i32.const', value: number }
  | { type: 'i32.add', left: Expression, right: Expression };
```

And I want to create an object with the value of the 'type' property as key, and as value a function. Like so:

```
const visitor: Record<Instruction['type'], (instruction: Instruction) => void> = {
   'local.set': (instruction) => {},
   'i32.const': (instruction) => {},
   'i32.add': (instruction) => {},
}
```

But the typing of the 'instruction' parameter is too generic for me. I want to know which properties I can access on the instruction from within the function.
So how can I create a `Record` like type with all the keys of the 'type' property in the `Instruction` type, and their respective `Instruction` type as value?

In other words; Typescript can infer the type if I do this:

```
const instruction: Instruction = { type: 'local.set' }; // TS knows about the missing 'name' and 'value' properties
```

But I want to do something like:

```
const instruction: Instruction[where type = 'local.set'] = { type: 'local.set' };
```

Is that possible, and how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a custom mapped type to map over the union of `type` and then use the `Extract` conditional type to get the union constituent from `Instruction` that has the same type as the current property:

```
export type Instruction =
    | { type: 'local.set', name: string, value: Expression }
    | { type: 'i32.const', value: number }
    | { type: 'i32.add', left: Expression, right: Expression };

type Visitor<T extends { type: string}> = {
    [P in T['type']]: (instruction: Extract<T, { type: P }>) => void
}
const visitor: Visitor<Instruction> = {
    'local.set': (instruction) => { instruction.name},
    'i32.const': (instruction) => { instruction.value },
    'i32.add': (instruction) => {  instruction.right },
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmAThAziglgewHZQLxQDeAvgLABQECmiwUokUAktisIgK4DGwWueFKEKgAfIvXAQAXFADkAG0xcAhvIB0KCMFkAaKNmUBbaVDaJ02AOZ6Abqo4n4SVBhxQy5YaPEMTs9ADMAExqXDhsulB28g4y2ByGAEYQiO6CwmKEEpAy-sFqygAmhZHyEABmwDJOyGh8euaWABZVsAi1rrjEANwUFL5QAGroGMA0ADwAKlBUwBDYhSg+kjJmFpbEAHz4ROlCANoAClAWUJP7sr6yALrXMgAUFmbcvDjVcOzKPFN6Wb4yxy2AEp8NsbJh0IUKB4wqw6DYRugxogZMNRhMWM8eHxtgRCHs5IoVOpNNoHk92C8+CC8NsshTONicGoDMZiDoCXkQrCIuS4YzXtgaXSTvyqczog53BzPMIuQVirI+VjBcLxKKVXw1I0WtLoUA)